# Always index 0 when iterating over list

Tags: java, list

I keep getting the first object in the list when I try iterate.

code:

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Location> locations) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(locations);

            Log.d("Debug" , "List: " + locations.size() +  " markers");
            for (Location location : locations) {
                Log.d("Debug", "index of: " + locations.indexOf(location));
            }
        }
```

Print out says, 200 markers in list and printout of index gives "0" 200 times. 
How come it won't iterate to next object?

Comment: Did you implement equals() and hashCode() of the class Location ?

Comment: All 200 objects are uniqe. My bad

Comment: their identity might be unique but they all apparently pass `.equals()` against each other as `true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It is iterating to the next object correctly:

`.indexOf()` just considers every object at every index to be `.equals(location)` == `true` to the first one at index `0`.

#### Proof:

If you added the same `Location` 200 times and the `.equals()` isn't overridden correctly; for example where every instance is equal to every other instance; you are get back the first match.

The [List.indexOf(Object o)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29) Javadoc clearly states:

> Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in
>   this list, or `-1` if this list does not contain the element. More
>   formally, returns the lowest index i such that `(o==null ? get(i)==null
>   : o.equals(get(i)))`, or `-1` if there is no such index.

#### If `.equals()` thinks it is then you will get the first match.

In your case index `0`.

```
   public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        final List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>(100);
        for (int i=0; i<100; i++) { al.add("Hello World!"); }
        for (final String s : al)
        {
            System.out.println(al.indexOf(s));
        }
    }
```

Prints out `0` 100 times.

One simple change

```
    for (int i=0; i<100; i++) { al.add(Integer.toString(i)); }
```

And you see that the code works as intended with unique objects as considered by a correctly implemented `.equals()`

Comment: The equals method can still be implemented **correctly** and get this result. It is up to the programmer to decide how two `Location` objects are considered meaningfully equal.

Comment: @Rudi - that is a technicality since it is obvious that the OP considers all the instances unique and is expecting them to be unique. Given that expectation, `.equals()` is not behaving *correctly* in their case.

Comment: Touché, I withdraw my previous statement. +1. Although, I just spotted an issue with both of our `List<String>` examples. Because we are using literals to populate the array each index will refer to the same `String` object in the `String` constant pool. As such they would also pass the == test.

Comment: `==` doesn't matter, the implementation in the `List.indexOf()` only considers `.equals()` so identity comparison isn't a concern.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because `indexOf()` returns the first index of an instance of an object that `equals()` the object you are checking for and you must have many multiple `Location`s that are considered meaningfully equal. This could be because you have incorrectly overridden your equals method for `Location` or just not considered the implications of your specific override.

Take a look at the following example which demonstrates your issue except with `String` objects;

```
        ArrayList<String> als = new ArrayList<String>();
        als.add("a");
        als.add("b");
        als.add("c");
        als.add("d");
        als.add("e");

        for(String s : als) System.out.print(als.indexOf(s));

        als = new ArrayList<String>();
        als.add(new String("a"));
        als.add(new String("a"));
        als.add(new String("a"));
        als.add(new String("a"));
        als.add(new String("a"));
        System.out.println();
        for(String s : als) System.out.print(als.indexOf(s));
```

This outputs;

```
01234
00000
```

In the last 5 outputted `0`s, the `s` `String` you check the array for may be the 2nd or greater `String` in the array but it is found to be **meaningfully** equal (as defined by the `String` classes `equals()` override) to the `String` in the first index and so it will always return `0`. Try the above example with an array of objects instead, and they are never considered equal unless they are referring to the same object in memory.

Answer (score 0):

Normally `for (Location location : locations)` iterate over the objects in locations list.When  `indexOf()` is called it use equals and hashCode to find the specific object,  but  i think that you don't implement `equals` and `hashCode` methods of the class Location .Try to implement them and check.

Answer (score 0):

Validate ***equals method*** or validate the instance ***is not null***. This is the implementation for the method on ArrayList in order to understand why.

```
public int indexOf(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (elementData[i]==null)
                return i;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            if (o.equals(elementData[i]))
                return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```